# How to highlight one exact line in visual studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, line, highlighting

I want to have, for example, line 133 always be highlighted as blue (for example). Is there is a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a special comment to this line and use an extension like [CommentsPlus](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f76e86e3-03ca-4ac8-ba88-58c8f8d818f4) to display it with color.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I guess that's better way to achieve what i want.